# VB.net equivalent of C++ Code

Tags: c++, vb.net

What is the VB.net equivalent of the following code:

```
extern void * PASCAL EXPORT rclib_get_alarmmsg( int type, int num );
```

Particularly I want to know what the `*` does. I assume it's some kind of `ByRef` business but I don't know!

Just to give a bit more context, the following code:

```
extern short PASCAL EXPORT rclib_set_alarm(short ,short mactype = 0);
```

roughly translates to:

```
Declare Function rclib_set_alarm Lib "rbcutlib.dll" (ByVal FlibHndl As Short) As Short
```

So basically I'm trying to do the same translation with the first line of code but I'm not sure what the implications of the `void` and `*` are.

Comment: void and * mean that you are looking to return a pointer of any type - as long as your are returning a pointer to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

void* is IntPtr. rclib_get_alarmmsg return pointer to some structure (alarmmsg). void* is type-unsafe pointer.